# Failed custom build command using Cargo when including reqwest with rustls-tls in redhat 6

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, reqwest

1. in my Cargo.toml

```ini
reqwest = { version = "0.10", default-features = false, features = ["blocking", "json", "rustls-tls"] }
```

2. my rust version is 1.59 matched the glibc 2.15 in redhat 6
   when I run cargo check , the errors below:

```
Checking http-body v0.3.1
Checking unicode-normalization v0.1.22
error: failed to run custom build command for ring v0.16.20

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: /root/reqtest/target/debug/build/ring-4494a7af260ba106/build-script-build (exit status: 101)
--- stdout
OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
HOST_CC = None`your text`
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
CC = None
```

How could I use reqwest with rustls-tls via Rust 1.59 in redhat 6 ?

Comment: Seems like the build script hasn't found any c compiler.  Try to set correct env vars for your c compiler toolchains, or install gcc/clang.